# AKS not able to create new subnet new node pool in a seperate subnet

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, vnet

I am trying to create a new node pool in a newly created subnet with this command

```
az aks nodepool add \
    --resource-group nems12 \
    --cluster-name nems-cluster \
    --name aksperfnode \
    --node-count 1 \
    --vnet-subnet-id aks2
```

But getting an error `Agent pools subnet is not in Vnet CIDR` but it is actually added in vnet address space and a subnet is created for it

Comment: Could you please check that the subnet assigned to the AKS node pool is not a delegated subnet. Also the cluster identity used by the AKS cluster must have at least Network Contributor permissions on the subnet within your virtual network.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment its working fine for me. You need to provide `--vnet-subnet-id` in this format `/subscriptions/b83c1eXXXXX5ba-2bXXXXX23f/resourceGroups/v-raxXXXXee/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/TestVNET/subnets/AKS-Subnet`.

[image]

[image]

**Note : As [Andriy Bilous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14944568/andriy-bilous) also check that suggestion if you are still getting an error after followed my solution.**

- please check that the subnet assigned to the AKS node pool is not a delegated subnet.
- Select NSG as None for your existing Subnet. Which might sometime cause error.

[image]